Dynamic import of CommonJS yields different result between dev-server and production targets
My Angular 18 application is using the new Angular build system, utilising the "application" target for production builds, thus making my local "dev-server" target use vite.
Additionally, I'm using ngx-quill as a WYSIWYG with some custom modules, one of which is a package called '@enzedonline/quill-blot-formatter2'. This package uses CommonJS for it's modules, which seems to be causing me problems when attempting to lazy load the module implementation. The setup looks like this
quill.config.ts
import { defer } from 'rxjs';
import { QuillConfig } from 'ngx-quill';

export const quillConfig: QuillConfig = {
  theme: 'snow',
  format: 'json',
  ...more configuration...
  customModules: [
    {
      path: 'modules/blotFormatter',
      implementation: defer(() =>
        import('@enzedonline/quill-blot-formatter2/dist/BlotFormatter').then(qbf => {
          console.log(qbf);
          return qbf.default;
        })
      )
    }
  ]
};

When I enter a page which depends on quill, the implementation subscribes and the import runs, however depending on if it's running as a production build or a local dev server, I get differing outcomes. The console reports this on dev-server:

but this on the production build:

It almost feels like vite (and thus rollup?) and esbuild have differing opinions on how to handle the __esModule flag, one of which is wrapping up the export in a default export,  leading to a "double default" issue.
Does anyone have any advice on how to handle this issue? Of course I could always raise a feature request with the author of the package to add support for ES modules, but this still doesn't explain the odd behaviour.
My (undesired) workaround is as follows
type QuillBlotFormatterModule =
  | typeof import('@enzedonline/quill-blot-formatter2/dist/BlotFormatter')
  | { default: typeof import('@enzedonline/quill-blot-formatter2/dist/BlotFormatter') };

{
  path: 'modules/blotFormatter',
  implementation: defer(() =>
    import('@enzedonline/quill-blot-formatter2/dist/BlotFormatter').then(
      (qbf: QuillBlotFormatterModule) =>
        'default' in qbf.default ? qbf.default.default : qbf.default
    )
  )
}

Finally, here are a few settings in my tsconfig that may be of interest
"moduleResolution": "bundler",
"target": "es2022",
"module": "es2022",
"lib": ["es2022", "dom"],
"esModuleInterop": true

Thanks in advance

Looks like ngx-quill faced the same issue with quill package itself. They did the following https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/blob/2ed554b09140facded3b2dea93deaa32e86ab1f6/projects/ngx-quill/src/lib/quill.service.ts#L46
